# Effective Validation with Linq + System.Data.Entity

Tags: c#, linq, validation, logging

I'm working on a Discord.Net project and i'm trying to figure out a way of logging more effectively, as the way i'm doing it, feels a bit over the top!

Two examples of ways i'm thinking of doing it:

```
        var channel = new Channel();
        try
        {
            channel = database.Channels.Where(
                c => c.ChannelId == channelId)
                .Include(c => c.Server).Single();
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Log(LogSeverity.Error, 
                 $"{ClassName}/{MethodName} - {exception.Message}");
            return;
        }
```

And...

```
        var channel = database.Channels.Where(
            c => c.ChannelId == channelId)
            .Include(c => c.Server).ToList();

        if(channel.Count == 0)
        {
            Logger.Log(LogSeverity.Error, 
                "No channel found when attemtping to log a message.");
            return;
        }
        if(channel.Count > 1)
        {
            Logger.Log(LogSeverity.Critical, 
                "Multiple channels found when attemtping to log a message");
            return;
        }
```

I would really appreciate any tips and advise on this sort of thing :D

Comment: If it's a question about how extensively your logging should be it's really about personal taste and requirements to your app. Logging should be detailed enough to pinpoint where something goes wrong, yet general enough to not clutter your code... But again: personal taste.

Comment: I have an idea of how extensive I want to be with it. But felt that having to do two validation statements for each interaction with the database was too much. I've tried to simplify it down to a Validation class (passing in an instance of an "EFModel" instead of the individual model (eg. User or Channel)). With Single and Multiple checks. So that I could use Validation.Single(channels) for instance.

Comment: You're logging different things in both methods so we can't really compare them. Even then, this is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `OrDefault` methods for `First` and `Single`.

```
var channel = database.Channels
    .Include(c => c.Server)
    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ChannelId == channelId);

if (channel == null)
{
  Logger.Log(LogSeverity.Error, $"{ClassName}/{MethodName} - No model found");
  return;
}
```

I also removed the `try/catch` because if there is an Exception it should be propagated. If your relational data model is valid Single should never return more than 1 if you are filtering on the `Id`. If you are not filtering on `Id` and you only ever expect one then you should add a constraint (like a unique index) to ensure that the persisted data cannot become invalid.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this! I was trying to do something like this before, but I wasn't getting a null back. I don't really expect there to be multiple.. but if there is it will crash the application, which isn't really desirable.  

For instance at one point, there was a bug where a user was able to be added again due to the check for it already existing in the database failing. And when retrieving users later, it crashed the application.

Comment: @Panda - `there was a bug where a user was able to be added again due to the check for it already existing in the database failing` <= I would recommend that you sanitize the now entered "bad" data, run some scripts to fix it so that the code can be written correctly.